# Message sent from .net System.Net.Mail is not visible on BlackJack II Windows Mobile

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'm sending a message from my ASP.net page to an email account, the message is sent properly and is viewable in Thunderbird or any other email client I use.

But I can not view the message text in my Windows Mobile 6.1 (BlackJacK II) device, I've played around with setting

```
    msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
```

or

```
    msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

or even

```
    msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
```

but none of these work and message body is simply not visible on the device.

the code to send the message is below

Where Body is an ASP.net TextBox control

```
 try
  {
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("test@test.com", "test@test.com");
    msg.Subject = "[TestProduct - TestPage.aspx]";
    msg.Body = Body.Text;
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("localhost");
    sc.Send(msg);
    txtMsg.Text = "Thank you for contacting TestCompany Inc someone will contact you promptly.";
  }
  catch
  {
    txtMsg.Text = "Unable to send your message at this time, Please try again later. Sorry for inconvineance.";
  }
```

When the IsBodyHtml = false and I do not set the Encoding these are the headers that I receive

```
From - Tue Jun 09 11:48:23 2009
Received: from chronos ([127.0.0.1]) by chronos.lunarpages.com with MailEnable ESMTP; Tue, 09 Jun 2009 11:45:09 -0700
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: Removed
To: Removed
Date: 9 Jun 2009 11:45:09 -0700
Subject: [TestProduct - TestPage.aspx]
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Return-Path: <Removed>

test this message
```

and still I'm unable to see it in device.

Comment: Are you sure your message body (Body.Text) is HTML?

Comment: I've tried with IsBodyHtml = false as well, actually the Body is not html and simple text

Comment: What exactly happens on the mobile device?

You can see the message, but it doesn't have any text in it?

Comment: Yes the message arrives and I can see the subject text but when I open the message it does not show any text in it.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a test, I'd try:

- don't set IsBodyHtml at all
- set Subject to "foo" (that literal string)
- set Body to "bar" (that literal string)

that should give the simplest mail - if it works, change one thing at a time until it breaks :)

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the blackjack is set to receive HTML emails.

Comment: My device is set to receive HTML messages

Answer (score 0):

I feel its the issue with your Mobile device. Did you try another device? Which browser are you using? Check your browser settings.

Comment: I'm using the default outlook client to receive messages, is that what you meant?

Comment: If you are using outlook then choose the account and select "Doanload size settings" and make sure Message Format is selected as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The mail client on the BlackJack probably cannot display HTML messages.  Most email programs generate plain-text versions of the messages that they send.  However, `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` does not do this automatically.

You can create an `AlternateView` object with a plain text version of the message by like this

```
string plainTextVersion = //... 
msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateFromString(plainTextVersion, null, "text/plain");
msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateFromString(Body.Text, null, "text/html");
```

**EDIT**: If the device can display HTML messages, this won't solve the problem.

Comment: I tried this and it still doesn't work
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(Body.Text, null, "text/plain"));

Answer (score 0):

Can you view the raw message on the mobile device? If so, I'd post it for some of the experts here. it would help greatly to see what's MIME parts the device attempting to render.